# Как программно активировать кнопку?

Tags: java

Создал кнопку и два текстовых поля. Хочу сделать так, чтобы кнопка была активна только если оба этих поля заполнены. Как это сделать?
Пробовал вот так:

```
private void jTextField1InputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) { //первое поле                                                  
        jButton1.setEnabled(jTextField1.getText().length() != 0 && jTextField2.getText().length() != 0);
    }                                                  
 
private void jTextField2InputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {               //второе поле                                    
        jButton1.setEnabled(jTextField1.getText().length() != 0 && jTextField2.getText().length() != 0);
    }
```

Это по аналогии с C#, но не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен TextWatcher:

```
 AppCompatEditText et1 =  findViewById(R.id.edt);
 AppCompatEditText et2 =  findViewById(R.id.et2);
 Button btn = findViewById(R.id.bt);
    
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (et1.getText().length() > 0 && et2.getText().length() > 0) {
                btn.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    };

    et1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: А обязательно прямо весь этот код писать? Какой смысл от первых двух функций в конструкторе?

Comment: Да, обязательно. Мы должны переопределить все методы интерфейса. Но если нам не нужна реализация каких-либо из этих методов, мы можем оставить их пустыми. Выглядит не очень лаконично, но это обычная практика в java/kotlin

Comment: Понятно, спасибо